# Why KeyValuePair missing values while fetching documents using Query in Firebase Firestore in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I have collection like this

[image]

I am trying to get name and score for Leaderboard but score is missing for first name as shown below

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public void GetLeaderboardData()
    {

        Firebase.Firestore.Query allUsersQuery = db.Collection("users").OrderByDescending("timestamp").Limit(20);
        allUsersQuery.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
            QuerySnapshot allUsersQuerySnapshot = task.Result;
            foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in allUsersQuerySnapshot.Documents)
            {
                //Debug.Log (String.Format ("Document data for {0} document:", documentSnapshot.Id));
                Dictionary<string, object> user = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in user)
                {
                    Debug.Log(String.Format("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));

                    if (pair.Key == "score")
                    {
                        score = (string)pair.Value;
                    }

                    if (pair.Key == "name")
                    {
                        uname = (string)pair.Value;
                        GameObject tBar = Instantiate(postPrefab.gameObject, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                        tBar.transform.SetParent(PostParent, false);
                        tBar.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = score;
                        tBar.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>().text = uname;
                        tBar.gameObject.name = documentSnapshot.Id;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

What I am doing wrong? Can anyone help Please?

Comment: Can you log what's coming in to ensure that there's nothing funky going on with `GetChild`? Is there anything in the editor log that might be useful? Firestore is still in beta for games, are you on the latest (7.2.0)?

Comment: @PatrickMartin I did `Debug.Log(String.Format("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));` Log is coming fine. and yes I checked everything for GetChild, and also yes im using latest Firebase version.

Comment: So you did see "score" "<some score here>" for all your entries and it's just not showing up in your UI?